# How can I interpolate the result of a function in a Perl here doc?

Tags: perl

I was wondering if it was possible to call a function inside a Perl *here* doc

```
sub Function
{
}

print<<HERE;

  Function()

HERE
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the function's return value to be interpolated into the heredoc?

```
sub Function {
    qw( Hello, World! );
}

print <<HERE;

  @{[ Function() ]}

HERE
```

To explain the syntax, [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=484242) says:

The `@{}` interpolates an array into your here-doc, and the inner `[]` creates an anonymous array, whose elements consist of whatever expression(s) you want to put between them.

Comment: See also [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod)